# Shopify Admin GraphQL API for getting orders of a particulate date

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am using GraphQL Admin API for fetching orders data for particulate date.
Below query I am using to fetch data but it gives wrong data.

```
$created_at_min =  \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(8)->toDateTimeString();

$created_at_max = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(8)->addHours(23)->addMinutes(59)->addSeconds(59)->toDateTimeString();

$query = '{
          orders(first:10, query : "created_at_min:'.$created_at_min.',created_at_max:'.$created_at_max.'"){
            edges{
              node{
                name
                totalPriceSet{
                  presentmentMoney{
                    amount
                    currencyCode
                  }
                }
                customer{
                  firstName
                  lastName
                  phone
                  email
                }
                lineItems(first : 10){
                  edges{
                    node{
                      product{
                        handle
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }';
```

I am adding a screenshot of the graphQL app of Shopify. I am getting proper data using REST API but wrong data only using GraphQL API. I am definitely making a blunder in writing graphQL Query.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what you mean by wrong data. Additionally, showing your code for dates without showing what your code renders is not helpful. If your dates are screwed, then of course your data is wrong. Try being a little more descriptive, and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time David Sir, I have paste a screenshot from the GraphQL shopify app in the question.

Comment: Hi did you figure this out?

Comment: Following is how it can we filtered. (query:"created_at:>='2021-05-20T00:00:00-07:00' AND created_at:<='2021-05-20T23:59:59-07:00'")